# Check if `isql` queries succeed

Tags: sql, linux, isql

Is there any way to check if an `isql` query has failed? It seems `isql` returns 0 whether queries succeed or not, only returning false if there was a error connecting to the server. How can I determine whether or not my Sybase queries work from the command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`--retserverror` seemed to be what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Just Run this commands

```
 isql -v SERVERNAME Username password
```

At the prompt run your query

```
>SELECT COUNT (*) FROM table

+------+
|      |
|  100 |    
+------+
```

If you dont get any value back there is some problems

Comment: Im asking if you can check that a query has failed not if *isql* has failed.